# How to disable Airplay on IPad?

Tags: ipad, airplay

Is it possible to disable Airplay on an iPad?  I recently bought a Denon receiver that supports Airplay.  The other day my 2 year old niece decided to stream what she was watching on the iPad to my stereo at an extremely high volume level.  As you could imagine, trying to tell a 2 year old not to do something can be impossible at times, so I'd like to disable the Airplay feature from the iPad so my niece, and others, can't use it.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to disable AirPlay.
However you could add a volume limit with Restrictions. Also with iOS 6 you can have more control over how kids control the iPad with Guided Access. You can limit the iPad to just the current app and lock off parts of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Or.., buy a router with a seperate guest network and have the kids toy access the Internet via this. Only solution for the ipod .

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any AirPlay-specific restrictions available on the iOS side yet. Another approach would be to either disable or password-protect AirPlay on your home theather's end, not on the iPad.

Apple TV provides both of these options, for example. Unfortunately, based on my research, it doesn't appear to be possible to disable or password protect AirPlay on Denon receivers  at this time.